# How to determine navy blue and grey combo for logo/ business card?

Tags: color

How to figure out which navy blue and grey will print best (be most legible) with digital business card printing process?

Comment: You'd typically use your eyes to pick out what looks good to you then do some test prints to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

First if all the obvious but still important, for print you work only on CMYK and you need to consider that it will probably still be a bit darker than what you see on the screen.

For grey and navy I would seek contrast, use a relatively dark shade of navy and a light shade of grey to create a high contrast.
These colors and be similar since navy is sort of a low saturated blue so he careful!!

Also, sometimes we give the greys a slight blue-is tone tome make it a bit more alive, which is something that in your case you might want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty method is what DAO1 said in comment: test prints

But like Naty said contrast is important, especially when using a blue and gray.

The first thing I would do is avoid using any Cyan in the Gray. Just use a percentage of K. That will help keep things sharper than might otherwise appear.

Now select something that looks visually good to you. Before wasting time printing though, check either the HSB B-Value or the Lab L-Value. These are "Brightness" or "Lightness" and you don't want them to be close to each other. You can then play with these values without affecting the Hue that you selected.

Now that you have those a good ways apart from each other. I find 1:3 being a decent ratio to start with you should then test print and see. You might even setup a contact sheet with a few variations either of Hue or of the Lightness values to see which looks best to you.

There's also some websites that might help such as: http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/

Answer (score -1):

I would head to color.adobe.com and type in "blue gray" in search and look at all the different examples they have.

Comment: you're probably going to receive some downvotes because of how brief this is. It also doesn't touch at all on the reasoning behind it and specifically how the colors print. Might want to [edit] your answer with more information